# Updating field in CRM 2011 through javascript from ribbon button on homegrid view

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to create a button on the initial list or homegrid view of leads that will set the value of a specific field to the same value every time for the lead that is selected.  Anyone know how i can do this through javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: I have created the button and have been attempting to use variations of Xrm.Page.getAttribute(“po_CRMFieldSchemaName”).setValue(‘My New Value’);    I am thinking that this is not going to work since I am not on the form and will have to access the data using something else.

Comment: Yeah, that's right, you won't be able to do it this way.

Answer (score 2):

To build on James's answer, you can use the `CrmParameter` `SelectedControlSelectedItemIds` to get a list of all the leads selected in a homepage grid. There is [an answer on the MSDN forums](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/is/crmdevelopment/thread/382bde52-b7a1-488e-8145-56a38eeb442a) that explains how to do this, copied below. You can do this in the Xml source or in the two CRM ribbon editors I know of.

After that, you would then need to use the `Update` method of one of the CRM webservices to loop through the `Guid` array and update each entity/database row accordingly. I've mentioned [Avanade's excellent web resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358482/how-to-link-two-records-with-javascript-and-a-nm-relationship/7363201#7363201) before, and MSDN has some additional documention on this as well.

- [Walkthrough: Use the SOAP Endpoint for Web Resources with JScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg594434.aspx)
- [Sample: Create, Retrieve, Update and Delete Using the REST Endpoint with JavaScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334427.aspx)

```xml
<CommandDefinition Id="Account.Form.CustomGroup.Button.A.Command">
  <Actions>
    <JavaScriptFunction Library="$webresource:AccountFormLibrar"
                        FunctionName="CreateNewAccount">
      <CrmParameter Value="SelectedControlSelectedItemIds"/>
    </JavaScriptFunction>
  </Actions>
</CommandDefinition>
```

```
function CreateNewAccount (prmRecordGUID) {
    //prmRecordGUID will recieve all GUIDS in comma seperated i.e. GUID1,GUID2,GUID3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah this should be pretty straightforward - I dont think what you have said in your comment will work - that function you are trying to use only works if the form of the record is open, e.g. it wont work from a grid view.

You will have to use a webservice call as described in the MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771584#BKMK_DataAccessUsingJavaScript

Also if you are customising the ribbon (adding buttons) you would find it a lot easier with this tool: http://www.develop1.net/public/page/Ribbon-Workbench-for-Dynamics-CRM-2011.aspx