# javascript onsave event firing from "homepage" view

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I have written some javascript and attached it onto the onSave event of an entity to perform some actions when a record is deactivated. This works fine when on the form but if a user decides to deactivate the record from the entity view then this code does not get fired. Is there a way that I can attach this event to deactivating from here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to create plugin if you want to perform some action that doesn't take place on the actual form itself, or a button on the ribbon.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939071/updating-field-in-crm-2011-through-javascript-from-ribbon-button-on-homegrid-vie) similar question

Comment: Is it possible to get the save mode to check for deactivating in a plugin like you can with javascript?

Comment: Yes that is possible with the plugin. You just check if the status == deactivated.

Comment: A plugin is a much better solution to this problem because it will cover situations such as when a workflow deactivates the record (which JavaScript can't).

Comment: Correct, he has to decide for himself what is best in his scenario. I wanted to give him all the available options so he could make a good choice of which approach he is going to use

Answer (score 1):

You can use the a Ribbon Editor to edit the "deactivate" Ribbon Button in the homepage grid to include a javascript function in a webresource. So when it is clicked the button will trigger your javascript code.

the only adjustment you have to make is to accept an input parameter given by the ribbon button.

You just need to make a RibbonButton and set a control so that it will return all the id's of the active grid. In the link you will have the "SelectedControlSelectedItemIds" but you have more options available.

if you alter the XML of the solution. Your function will require a parameter.

```
function getSelectedItems(arrayOfIDS){
     for(var i = 0; i < arrayofIDS.length;i++)
     {
         //Your implementation here
     }
}
```

Alternatively you can choose to write a plugIn like Daryl suggests

EDIT: [Ribbon Workbench](http://www.develop1.net/public/page/Ribbon-Workbench-for-Dynamics-CRM-2011.aspx): With this tool you can customize system buttons with visual ribbon button you can't.

Comment: From what I can see I can't add any more functions to the deactivate button (or any other system buttons), or edit it in any way at all. Am I missing something?